# Fatal error on phpMyAdmin

Tags: codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I want to configure my database on `CI` but I have a problem

[image]

How can i fix it?
I'm using `CI 2.x`
And
`phpMyAdmin-4.6.6-english`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can check your using wrong database settings in your **database.php** file.

If your `php` version is equals to `php 5.5` or above you have to use

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

instead of

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

and also put your database `username` and `password` in setting to avoid this error.

I recommend you to use `codeigniter 3` the latest version .

Comment: Thank you very much